# How to correctly manage fetch errors response with observables and RxJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rxjs, observable, redux-observable

I just recovered a simple auth app built with *ReactJS*, *redux-observable* and *RxJS*.
I want to implement an error handler when the API backend send a response > `400`.

Actually, there is an *epic* that handle login process on `LOGIN_REQUEST` event:

```
const apiLoginEpic = (action$, state$) =>
  action$.pipe(
    ofType(authConstant.LOGIN_REQUEST),
    mergeMap(action => authService.loginApi(action.username, action.password)),
    map(({ body }) => extractJwtPayload(body.token)),
    map(authAction.login.apiSuccess),
    logObservableErrorAndTriggerAction(authAction.login.apiFailure)
```

This *epic* just call a service, which is a simple fetch that refer to:

```
const fetchBackend = (path, options = {}, withCredentials = false) => {
  fetch(`${process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL}${path}`, options)
    .then(response =>
      response.status < 400
        ? Promise.all([response, response.json()])
        : Promise.reject(response)
    )
    .then(([response, body]) => ({
      status: response.status,
      headers: response.headers,
      body,
    }))
}
```

As you can see, when the response status is superior to `400`, it reject the promise. Then, in the *epic* (first code extract), the error is catch in `logObservableErrorAndTriggerAction` function which is implemented as:

```
const logObservableErrorAndTriggerAction = action =>
  catchError((response, source) =>
    pipe(
      tap(logger.error),
      () => of(action(response)).pipe(merge(source))
    )(response)
  )
```

My problem is that I want to catch the response body in `logObservableErrorAndTriggerAction`, which can be reusable.
Unfortunately, I don't have much knowledge about *observalbes* and *RxJS*.

When I try to use body of the response, it appears that it is a `ReadableStream`. I tried a lot of things but I can't turn it into JSON :

```
{
  body: ReadableStream,
  bodyUsed: false,
  headers: Headers {},
  ok: false,
  redirected: false,
  status: 400,
  statusText: "",
  type: "cors",
  url: "http://localhost/api/login"
}
```

Does anybody know how to manage my use case ?

Thank you very much,
Sylvain

Comment: Suggest you read up on the `Streams API` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Streams_API).

Comment: Add console.log to check what is real value you resolve promise with, (response.json())

Comment: And I dont think it is rxjs related issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answers.
We are going to replace redux-observable with redux-saga. We think that RxJS syntax is a little too hard for us. Thank you for your help